# ¿Como unificar tres registros de una table en otra en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Poseo un sistema que diariamente realiza una inspection general de todo el proceso laboral, asignándole unos determinados valores.

Cada inspección esta formada por 3 etapas, donde cada etapa posee su propio conjunto de valores (3 registros).

Las tablas son las siguientes:

```
--INSPECCION--
ID_inspeccion
fecha
hora_inspeccion
etapa
realizador

--CALCULOS--
ID_calculo
valores

--INSPECCION_CALCULOS--
ID_inspeccion_calculo
inspeccion_fk
calculo_fk
```

### La relacion es la siguiente:

**INSPECCION** guardara un id único por cada registro, junto a la fecha, hora y la etapa de la inspección.

*Serian 3 registros en la base de datos*.

**INSPECCION_CALCULOS** guardara el id de la inspeccion a la que pertenece el grupo de calculos y los id de cada grupo de calculos.

*Serian 9 registros, pues 3 veces que aparece la inspeccion, mas 3 grupos de calculos*.

**CALCULOS** guarda los valores de los calculos que corresponden a cada etapa de la inspection general.

*Este es un string con valores*.

### Un ejemplo seria de un día de inspección seria:

```
--INSPECCION--
ID_inspeccion | fecha | hora |etapa
1 | 1-3-2018 | 9am  | primera 
2 | 1-3-2018 | 2pm  | segunda
3 | 1-3-2018 | 11pm |tercera

--CALCULOS--
ID_calculo |valores
1 | 100, 200, 300
2 | 100, 200, 300
3 | 100, 200, 300
4 | 100, 200, 300
5 | 100, 200, 300
6 | 100, 200, 300
7 | 100, 200, 300
8 | 100, 200, 300
9 | 100, 200, 300

--INSPECCION_CALCULOS--
ID_inspeccion_calculo | inspeccion_fk | calculo_fk
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 1 | 3
4 | 2 | 4
5 | 2 | 5
6 | 2 | 6
7 | 3 | 7
8 | 3 | 8
9 | 3 | 9
```

Ya tengo lista la insercion y la vista de los datos.

Hago mis consultas usando la fecha, pues no debería repetirse la fecha sino tres veces diariamente, por lo que obtengo el grupo de las 3 inspecciones.

**Mi problema esta**: al querer centralizar estos tres registros de inspeccion general en una tabla, no se como generar un id unico para cada colección de tres registros, con el fin de borrar los registros facilmente.

**Pregunto:** *¿Estaría eficaz borrar por fecha, validando (asegurando) que solo sean tres registros por día y que no puedan haber mas con la misma fecha?.*

Pense en generar una tabla llamada central asi:

```
--CENTRAL--
id | id_central | inspeccion_fk
```

Y que quedara algo asi:

```
**CENTRAL**
id | id_central | inspeccion_fk
1 | 1 | 1 
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 1 | 3
```

Donde el `id_central` sea un valor único por día.

**¿Como puedo unificar estos tres registros por dia?
¿Alguna forma de auto incrementar cada 3 registros?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas tres tablas, te basta con dos. Lo que estás usando es una relación "uno a muchos", que es un tipo de relación extremadamente habitual y muy estudiada. Esencialmente, cada `CALCULO` siempre pertenece a una y sólo una `INSPECCION`, así que puede almacenar el ID de ésta última en un campo dedicado.

```
**INSPECCION**
id
fecha
etapa
realizador

**CALCULO**
id
inspeccion_id
valores
```

Así, puedes cargarlo todo con un JOIN:
    SELECT * FROM `INSPECCION` INNER JOIN `CALCULO` ON INSPECCION.id = CALCULO.inspeccion_id WHERE id=?

Donde "?" es el id de la inspección a cargar.

Para almacenarlo, necesitarías primero hacer un INSERT sobre INSPECCION y luego, usando el ID de esa transacción, INSERTar los CALCULOs.

Sin embargo, te recomiendo fervientemente usar un ORM para facilitarte la vida (la elección del ORM dependerá del lenguaje que estés usando y eventualmente del framework si lo hay).

Comment: me parece bien, pero como haria en el caso del valor de etapa que cambia?, al igual que la hora de cada etapa de inspeccion

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: cada inspeccion (son tres diarias) guarda dos valores que cambian: la hora de la inspeccion y la etapa(un numero entero).

En la tabla de calculos seguiendo lo que me dices deberia agregar el id de la inspeccion y quedaria solucionado, por una parte.

ahora queda la duda, donde coloco el valor de la etapa y de la hora? (ya que cambian segun la inspeccion realizada)

lo deberia colocar en la tabla de calculos?

Comment: Cada valor debe ir en la tabla que le sea apropiada. Si hay una etapa y hora por cada inspección, entonces el lugar apropiado es en la tabla INSPECCION. Si por el contrario hay una por cálculo, entonces en CALCULO.

Comment: Procedi a eliminar la tabla inspeciones_calculos y dejar solo calculos

Comment: hay una por inspeccion, pero la idea que deseo implementar, es como hacer para centralizar los tres datos de las inspecciones diarias, o estaria bien manejar por asi decirlo como un ID unico de ese grupo la fecha del dia?

Comment: No, los IDs los debe gestionar directamente la base de datos (en MySQL, con campos AUTOINCREMENT, por ejemplo). Cada ID es único a un registro. Si quieres encontrar las inspecciones de un mismo día, puedes hacer una búsqueda sobre el campo fecha (p.ej., en la query que he puesto en la respuesta, cambias lo de después del WHERE con "INSPECCION.fecha = '2018-03-01' u otra fecha)

Comment: Por cierto, un artículo sencillo sobre arquitectura de bases de datos: https://www.uno-de-piera.com/relaciones-en-bases-de-datos-mysql/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73907/discussion-between-vaavdev-and-delcano).